# All faces change to selected material

Tags: materials

[image]Why when i select 1 face and want to change that single face to a specific material does the whole object change to the chosen material.

Comment: The first material applies to the whole object - to add a material to a select set of faces, press the plus (+) button on the right of the materials box to add a new material slot. Then, press the other plus (+) button _below_ the box to create a new material for that slot. With the desired faces selected, press **Assign**.

Comment: Thank you that helped :)